How to correctly use blind source separation for jamming suppression?
 I want to extract the target signal and remove noise using blind source separation algorithm. .
I have used this code:
def abs_sqr(W,X):
return abs(W.conj().T.dot(X))**2
def complex_FastICA(X,epsilon=.1,algorithm='parallel',
max_iter=100,tol=1e-4,whiten=True,
w_init=None,n_components=None):
"""Performs Fast Independent Component Analysis of complex-valued
signals
Parameters
----------

X : array, shape (n_features,n_samples)
    Input signal X = A S, where A is the mixing 
    matrix and S the latent sources.

epsilon : float, optional
    Arbitrary constant in the contrast G function 
    used in the approximation to neg-entropy.

algorithm : {'parallel', 'deflation'}, optional
    Apply a parallel or deflational FASTICA algorithm.

w_init : (n_components, n_components) array, optional
    Initial un-mixing array.If None (default) then an 
    array of normally distributed r.v.s is used.

tol: float, optional
    A positive scalar giving the tolerance at which the
    un-mixing matrix is considered to have converged.

max_iter : int, optional
    Maximum number of iterations.

whiten : boolean, optional
    If True, perform an initial whitening of the data.
    If False, the data is assumed to be already white.

n_components : int, optional
    Number of components to extract. If None, 
    n_components = n_features.

Returns
-------

W : array, shape (n_components, n_components)
    Estimated un-mixing matrix.

K : array, shape (n_components, n_features)
    If whiten is 'True', K is the pre-whitening matrix 
    projecting the data onto the principal components. 
    If whiten is 'False', K is 'None'.

EG : array, shape(n_components,max_iter)
    Expectation of the contrast function E[G(|W'*X|^2)]. 
    This array may be padded with NaNs at the end.

S : array, shape (n_samples, n_components)
    Estimated sources (S = W K X).
"""

n,m  = X.shape

if n_components!=None:
    n = n_components

if whiten:
    X-=X.mean(1,keepdims=True)
    Ux,Sx = eig(np.cov(X))
    K     = np.sqrt(inv(np.diag(Ux))).dot(Sx.conj().T)[:n]
    X     = K.dot(X)
    del Ux,Sx
else:
    K = None

EG = np.ones((n,max_iter))*np.nan

if algorithm=='deflation':

    W = np.zeros((n,n),dtype=complex)

    for k in range(n):
        if w_init!=None:
            w = w_init[:,k]
        else:
            w = np.random.normal(size=(n,1))+\
                1j*np.random.normal(size=(n,1))

        w/=norm(w)

        n_iter  = 0

        for i in range(max_iter):

            wold = np.copy(w)

            #derivative of the contrast function
            g  =  1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))
            #derivative of g
            dg = -1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))**2

            w  = (X * (w.conj().T.dot(X)).conj() * g).mean(1).reshape((n,1))-\
                 (g + abs_sqr(w,X) * dg).mean() * w

            del g,dg

            w/=norm(w)

            # Decorrelation
            w-=W.dot(W.conj().T).dot(w)
            w/=norm(w)

            EG[k,n_iter] = (np.log(epsilon+abs_sqr(w,X))).mean()

            n_iter+=1

            lim = (abs(abs(wold)-abs(w))).sum()
            if lim<tol:
                break

        if n_iter==max_iter and lim>tol:
            warnings.warn('FastICA did not converge. Consider increasing '
                          'tolerance or the maximum number of iterations.')

        W[:,k] = w.ravel()

elif algorithm=='parallel':

    if w_init!=None:
        W = w_init
    else:
        W = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))+\
            1j*np.random.normal(size=(n,n))

    n_iter = 0

    #cache the covariance matrix
    C = np.cov(X)

    for i in range(max_iter):

        Wold = np.copy(W)

        for j in range(n):

            #derivative of the contrast function
            g  =  (1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(W[:,j],X))).reshape((1,m))
            #derivative of g
            dg = -(1/(epsilon+abs_sqr(W[:,j],X))**2).reshape((1,m))

            W[:,j]  = (X * (W[:,j].conj().T.dot(X)).conj() * g).mean(1)-\
                      (g + abs_sqr(W[:,j],X) * dg).mean() * W[:,j]
            del g,dg

        # Symmetric decorrelation
        Uw,Sw = eig(W.conj().T.dot(C.dot(W)))
        W     = W.dot(Sw.dot(inv(np.sqrt(np.diag(Uw))).dot(Sw.conj().T)))
        del Uw,Sw

        EG[:,n_iter] = (np.log(epsilon+abs_sqr(W,X))).mean(1)

        n_iter+=1

        lim = (abs(abs(Wold)-abs(W))).sum()
        if lim < tol:
            break

    if n_iter==max_iter and lim>tol:
        warnings.warn('FastICA did not converge. Consider increasing '
                      'tolerance or the maximum number of iterations.')

S = W.conj().T.dot(X)

return K,W,S,EG

and as an input to the bss algorithm I am passing all the range gates. The first problem is that since the source is unknown, I don't have a value for n_component and if i keep n_component as None then the S matrix (whose each row is supposed to contain the independent source signals) is having the same no.of rows as the no.of range gates.
Can anyone be kind enough to suggest how to proceed?
[![I have also attached the waveform of the target signal that has been obtained after processing the data with STAP] for one range gate3]3

